# Javascript and RegEx: match function returns an array

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string:

```
var doi_id= "10.3390/metabo1010001"
```

And I would like to match only the first serie of digits from the end.

For that, I am using this regEx:

```
var doinumericpart = doi_id.match(/(\d*)$/);
```

The "problem" (or not) is that doinumericpart returns

```
1010001,1010001
```

instead of 1010001 and I don't know why.

When I am trying this regex here: http://regexr.com?31htm everything seems to work fine.

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: try removing the parentheses after `\d*` and just have `\d*$`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`match()` returns an array like it's supposed to. The first element is the whole substring that matched the pattern, then the first one onwards contain the subpatterns.

In your case, just get rid of the `()` - you don't need them since they enclose the whole pattern.

```
var doinumericpart = doi_id.match(/\d*$/)[0];
```

The `[0]` dereferences the array to give you the exact element you want.

Comment: Select the answer as the accepted answer then :) Give the man some credit

Answer (score 4):

`match` returns either `null` or an array of the matches. The amount of matches depends on how many capturing groups you have in your regex. The item at `[1]` will be your match so you can do:

```
var doinumericpart = doi_id.match(/(\d*)$/)[1]; //Access second item in the matches array
```

Answer (score 2):

`match` returns the complete match and each capturing group or `null` if there were no matches.

This is useful if you want to provide some context:

```
"10.3390/metabo1010001".match(/metabo(\d*)/)
// => ["metabo1010001", "1010001"]
```

- `metabo1010001` is the whole match
- `1010001` is the first capturing group